# Error while using pymc3 and Theano-PyMC package

Tags: python, c++, theano, pymc3

I am trying to use AutomatedRecommendationTool - A machine learning Automated Recommendation Tool for guiding synthetic biology. It uses a package named pymc3. But there are some issues regarding the compiler.
Following is the Error:

```
Exception: ('Compilation failed (return status=1): C:\\Users\\vaibh\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0-AMD64_Family_23_Model_96_Stepping_1_AuthenticAMD-3.9.12-64\\tmpqepy79wz\\mod.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in\r.  #include <Python.h>\r.  \r. ', 'FunctionGraph(Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}(TensorConstant{3.141592653589793}, TensorConstant{0.01}))')
```

Following is the code cell that I am trying to run:

```
%%time
if run_art:
    art = RecommendationEngine(df, **art_params)
else:
    with open(os.path.join(art_params['output_directory'], 'art.pkl'), 'rb') as output:
        art = pickle.load(output)
```

I am using a jupyter notebook for executing the code.

Following are the system specifications -

Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics 3.00 GHz

System type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

Operating System: Windows 10

I have also installed a c++ compiler (MingW):

```
C:\Users\vaibh>g++ --version
g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It seems that this error is related to theano, I tried to view the GitHub issues of theano but it doesn't seem to be helpful.

Following are the packages that I have installed -

1. pipenv: 2022.5.2
2. depinfo: 1.7.0
3. python-libsbml(or just libsbml): 5.19.5
4. rfc3986: 2.0.0
5. h11: 0.13.0
6. rich: 12.4.4
7. pydantic: 1.9.1
8. diskcache: 5.4.0
9. importlib_resources: 5.7.1
10. Semver: 2.13.0
11. Pathvalidate: 2.5.0
12. pydoe: 0.3.8
13. tpot: 0.11.7
14. edd-utils: 0.0.12
15. pytorch: 1.11.0
16. mpi4py: 3.1.3
17. pymc3: 3.11.4
18. blas: 1.0

Update: Theano-PyMC:1.1.2 was also installed as a dependency

Comment: what do you mean with `%%time`. This usage causes error

Comment: The solution provided by other answers are for linux based operating systems but I am using a Windows 10 operating system.